# PHP/Javascript - Displaying markers on google map from mysql database in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a while loop that displays data from my database such as name address etc. I would like the google map to loop through with the addresses from the database. currently, the google map only shows up once and I don't think its loops the same address which is lists next to the map.

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY-HERE]&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"async defer></script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

echo "<div class='result-container'>

    <div class='result-wrap'>

        <div class='leftbox'> 

            <div class='titlebox'>
                <h2>" . $row['company_name'] . "</h2>
            </div>

            <div class='box'>
                " . ((empty($row['address_1'])) ? '' : "<strong> Address: </strong>" . $row['address_1']) . ((empty($row['address_2'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['address_2']) . ((empty($row['town'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['town']) . ((empty($row['county'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['county']) . ((empty($row['postcode'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['postcode']) . "
            </div>

            <div class='box'>
                " . ((empty($row['tel'])) ? '' : "<strong> Telephone: </strong>" . $row['tel']) . ((empty($row['mobile'])) ? '' : "<strong> Mobile: </strong>" . $row['mobile']) . "
            </div>          

        </div> 

        <div class='rightbox'>

                <div class='service-pic'>
                 <img src='img/buddy.png' class='hvr-bob'>
                </div>                      

            <div id='map' style='width: 250px; height: 250px;'></div> 

        </div>

        </div><br/>";

  }

<script> 
    var address = "$row['address_1'], $row['town'], $row['postcode'], UK";  

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            zoom: 6
        });

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
            }, 
        function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
                });
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: you are printing php variable in javascript without php tag at `var address`

Comment: @AlbertAkki how would i correct this?

Comment: try var address = "<?=$row['address_1']?>, <?=$row['town']?>, <?=$row['postcode']?>, UK";

Comment: @AlbertAkki I have tried this, the google map still only shows up once in the while loop.

Comment: can you paste your browser source (CTRL+U) in pastebin? so that it will better understand what is exact issue. and post console error if any

Comment: @AlbertAkki I have pasted the page code into Pastebin http://pastebin.com/X6k6DwNf and there are no console errors.

Comment: Not your real source code please paste browser source which you will get by (CTRL+U) while running your website on browser

Comment: Here is the link to the source code http://pastebin.com/RQ6SJ1rG

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your code. First, you generate multiple `<div id="map"></div>` elements inside the loop. Id attribute must be unique within HTML page. After that you call a script outside the loop for the last row only. What do you try to implement?

Comment: @xomena eg. I search for a service cleaner in a search bar (in my full code) and it shows up with multiple results it shows the details and phone numbers along with the address this is all working but I want a map to show up and takes the address from that result. Fully Code [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/X6k6DwNf)

Comment: So you need a multiple map instances on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to create multiple instances of the map on the page.

You have to generate a code for `initMap()` JavaScript function that you specified as a callback in a script tag. This function will create multiple instances of the map, for this purpose, we can introduce `$counter` variable to be sure that we indeed have different instances. Also, I removed a signed_in parameter from the script tag as it was deprecated recently.

The code snippet is as the following:

```
 <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY-HERE]&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

    <?php
         $counter = 0;
         $jsInitFunction = "function initMap() { var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); ";
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<div class='result-container'>

              <div class='result-wrap'>

                  <div class='leftbox'>

                      <div class='titlebox'>
                          <h2>" . $row['company_name'] . "</h2>
                      </div>

                      <div class='box'>
                          " . ((empty($row['address_1'])) ? '' : "<strong> Address: </strong>" . $row['address_1']) . ((empty($row['address_2'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['address_2']) . ((empty($row['town'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['town']) . ((empty($row['county'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['county']) . ((empty($row['postcode'])) ? '' : ",&nbsp" . $row['postcode']) . "
                      </div>

                      <div class='box'>
                          " . ((empty($row['tel'])) ? '' : "<strong> Telephone: </strong>" . $row['tel']) . ((empty($row['mobile'])) ? '' : "<strong> Mobile: </strong>" . $row['mobile']) . "
                      </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class='rightbox'>

                          <div class='service-pic'>
                           <img src='img/buddy.png' class='hvr-bob'>
                          </div>

                      <div id='map" . $counter . "' style='width: 250px; height: 250px;'></div>

                  </div>

                  </div><br/>";

              $jsInitFunction .= "var address" . $counter . " = '" . $row['address_1'] . "," . $row['town'] . "," . $row['postcode'] .", UK';

                                 var map" . $counter . " = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map" . $counter .  "'), {
                                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                                      zoom: 6
                                 });

                                 geocoder.geocode({
                                    'address': address" . $counter . "
                                 }, function(results, status) {
                                      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                          new google.maps.Marker({
                                              position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                              map: map" . $counter . "
                                          });
                                          map" . $counter .  ".setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                    }
                                });";

              $counter++;
          }
          $jsInitFunction .= "}";
    ?>

    <script>
      <?php print $jsInitFunction; ?>
    </script>
```

Comment: I have implemented the code but I seem to be getting a 500 error, can't seem to figure out why I have posted my full code [here](http://pastebin.com/MCUdDJmS)

Comment: Look at line 131-133. Shouldn't `}` stay inside a `<?php ?>`

Comment: I have corrected that mistake but I'm still getting the same error there must be another issue I have updated the code http://pastebin.com/MCUdDJmS.

Comment: OK. You close `while` loop, you close `if` that situated before `while`. What about closing `if( isset( $_GET['k'], $_GET['t'] ) ){`? Seem to be unclosed.

Comment: got it the if wasn't closed, Thank you for your help.